Do women wear their best clothes on eid also or is it تبرج?
‏السلام عليكم
Do we wear nice clothes and smell nice or is that just for men?
‏جزاك الله خيرا

They can wear good clothes and use perfume in their homes, among mahrams. If they go out of their homes then they have to follow the same rules as normal times as the texts on veiling are general and apply regardless of the time of the year.

وأما النساء إذا خرجن فإنهن لا يتزين، بل يخرجن في ثياب البذلة، ولا يلبسن الحسن من الثياب ولا يتطيبن لخوف الافتتان بهن، وكذلك المرأة العجوز وغير ذوات الهيئة يجري ذلك في حكمها، ولا يخالطن الرجال بل يكن في ناحية منهم
As for women, if they go out, they do not adorn themselves. Rather, they go out in everyday clothes, and they do not wear good clothes and do not use perfume, because of the fear of fitnah. The same applies to old women and those who are not attractive. And they will not mingle with men, but rather will stay separate from them.
— Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah

Also see  https://islamqa.info/en/answers/49014/ and https://islamweb.net/en/fatwa/356683/
